# Cartridge heater frequency response

Tags: frequency-response, heater

Does anyone know the typical frequency response of a cartridge heater? Normally they work from 120/230 Vac 50/60 Hz, but I would like to know:

1. If it is possible to use a DC source (120/230 Vdc).
2. What would happen if the supply is 120/230 Vac, but higher frequency (50-100 kHz).

I imagine that the first case would work fine but, what about the second one? Would the cartridge be properly supplied? Could this reduce its lifetime?

Thanks!

Comment: You'd have to supply us details on the actual cartridge heater for anyone to answer this question

Answer (score 4):

Yes, you can use a DC source. Life might be reduced under some conditions but probably no ill effects.

The typical construction of a swaged cartridge heater is like this ) from [here](https://www.thermalcorporation.com/cartridge-heaters-tech-info):

[image]

As you can see, the internal construction is a coil of heater wire wound on MgO core and swaged into a nickel-iron-chromium alloy sheath with MgO powder filling.

At 100kHz the inductance in open air (ie if the sheath was not there) would be substantial, however it is likely that that, with the sheath, eddy currents induced in the sheath will cause hot spots in the resistance wire near the terminations and the heater will fail prematurely (perhaps very quickly) as the watt density limits will (locally) be greatly exceeded.

There's little reason I can think of to feed HF AC to a heater. Usually we time-proportion mains power to them with cycle times measured in seconds.